# Android SecureRandom fix (PRNGFixes) and "Prevention infomation" message

Tags: android, security

After adding PRNGFixes (http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/08/some-securerandom-thoughts.html) in the application, I have a problem with Samsung S4 devices. 
On those devices I get the message "Prevention infomation  has been forced to stop for unauthorized attempt to access the system in your device. It may be solved by the policy update service. It may be safe to delete an application obtained from an unauthorized route. Check now?" 
although the application is installed from Google Play.

How to modify the application so that such messages do not display?

Is there another solution besides removing PRNGFixes class?

Comment: Seems this message comes from the Samsung KNOX agent. I know this doesn't answer question but this article talks about how to prevent the message on rooted device:  http://wenlong.wordpress.com/2013/08/12/samsung-galaxy-s4-mini-i9190-rooted